# How to fix shapes not aligned when reading from CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to import a dataset from CSV file in Python, but it showed an error of "shapes not aligned". I wonder if anyone knows how to solve this.

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

x = genfromtxt('problem1.csv', delimiter=',')

def model(x,w):
    a = w[0] + np.dot(x.T,w[1:])
    return a.T

#define sigmoid function
def sigmoid(t):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-t))

#the convex cross-entropy cost function
def cross_entrypy(w):

    #compute sigmoid of model
    a = sigmoid(model (x,w))

    #compute cost of label 0 points
    ind = np.argwhere (y == 0) [:,1]
    cost = -np.sum(np.log(1 - a[:,ind]))

    #add cost on label 1 points
    ind = np.argwhere(y==1)[:,1]
    cost -= np.sum(np.log(a[:,ind]))

    #compute cross-entropy
    return cost/y.size

print(cross_entrypy([3,3]))
```

here is my dataset looks like

[image]

This is the error message I received
[image]

--update--

[image]

This is the practice question where the dataset is use for

Answer (score 1):

#### Array dimension

I am not sure what the meaning of your dataset is, but `x` has shape `(11,2)`, `w` has shape of `(1,)`.

#### Source of error

From your screenshot, the error is in `np.dot(x.T,w[1:])`. You cannot do dot product on `x.T` and `w[1:]`, because of the dimensionality mismatch.

#### Possible solutions

1. Simply add the line of `x=x[0]` or `x=x[1]`, right after `x = genfromtxt('problem1.csv', delimiter=',')`.
2. An alternative solution would be: change `np.dot(x.T,w[1:])` to `np.dot(x[0].T,w[1:])`, or `np.dot(x[1].T,w[1:])`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the use of dataset.

Comment: this create another issue which is "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1"

Comment: @cyw I think your `w` is not `[3,3]`. `w0=3, w1=3`, but there should be `w2, w3, ...`.